# Output for try / catch in Powershell Classes

Tags: powershell, class, try-catch

Experimenting with using classes in powershell, I'm uncertain how to display output. For instance in this code block the write-error does not display the error message:

```
class Test {
[string] $test 

    Test ([string] $test) {
        $this.test = $test
    }

    [test] Testfail() {
        try {
            Get-Childitem F:\ -ErrorAction stop

        } catch  {

            Write-Host  "ERROR!!! $this.test"
            Exit 1

        }
        return $this.test + "not an error!"
    }
}
```

In this case it's is obvious that the code runs the catch statement as the powershell window exits but if I comment out the Exit 1 the Write-Host message does not display. Can someone explain how to output the error?

Comment: As an aside: Commenting out the `Exit 1` _should_ make the `Write-Host` print. Are you sure it doesn't? What PowerShell version?

Comment: powershell seven preview 5

Comment: I do see the `Write-Host` output in both PowerShell Core 7.0.0-preview.6 and Windows PowerShell 5.1 (and I'm pretty sure that preview.5 acted the same).

Comment: Strange! I'm now trying this on 6.2.3 (macos) and 7(p6) and yes it's working as expected. Will have to re-try once I have my other laptop in hand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Only ever use `exit` to exit *script files* (`*.ps1`), not *class methods* or *functions*.**

Calling `exit` from a class method or function will instantly exit the PowerShell process *as a whole*.

**To report an error from a class method, use a *terminating error***, which is what `-ErrorAction Stop` or the `Throw` statement generate.

That is, simply use `Get-Childitem F:\ -ErrorAction stop` *without* `try` / `catch`, which **causes a (thread-)terminating error that the *caller* will have to catch.**

**If, by contrast, you simply want to issue an error *message* in your method, without affecting the flow of execution**, note that you cannot use `Write-Error` from a class method; however, you can **use `Write-Warning`** (`Write-Host` works too, but its use is not advisable).

- **Caveat**: **You cannot blindly use `return` to exit a method**, unless it is `[void]`-typed. You are forced to return an instance of the declared return type, and while `return $null` works well to signify "no return value" for *reference* types, using `return $null` with a *value* type such as `[int]` or `[datetime]` either converts the `$null` to that type (resulting in `0` for return type `[int]`) or *breaks* (for return type `[datetime]`, because `$null` cannot be meaningfully converted to that type).

---

In short: **Class methods in PowerShell behave differently from other PowerShell code**:

- To write to the success output stream, you must use the `return` statement; *implicit* output isn't supported.
- To report an error, you must generate a *terminating* error, either via common parameter `-ErrorAction Stop`, a `Throw` statement, or by calling a .NET method that generates an exception; *non-terminating* errors and attempts to write to the error stream directly with `Write-Error` are quietly *ignored*.
- All other outputs streams (see [about_redirection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_redirection)), however, *are* passed through.

This perhaps surprising discrepancy is discussed in [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/9702) and a request to clarify the behavior in the documentation can be found in [this GitHub docs issue](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/PowerShell-Docs/issues/4497).