# Write-Error doesn't result useful information when used inside class methods | Powershell

Tags: powershell, class, error-handling, write-error

I used a method with and without a class and the Write-Error seems to produce different outputs. In case of class, it doesn't specify the **function and the line number is always 1,1**

```
function oper1() {
    Try {
        [string] $cmd = ".\some_exe_which_does_not_exist.exe"
        iex $cmd 
    }
    Catch {
        Write-Error $_.Exception.Message
    }
}

oper1
```

Output for above:

> **oper1** : The term '.\some_exe_which_does_not_exist.exe' is not
>   recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable
>   program. Check the spelling of the  name, or if a path was included,
>   verify that the path is correct and try again. At
>   F:\debug\encryption_concat_tests\Untitled1.ps1:**11 char:1**
>   + **oper1**
>   + ~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Write-Error], WriteErrorException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WriteErrorException,oper1

When I enclosed the same function in a class, I got this:

```
class Operator {
    [void] oper1() {
        Try {
            [string] $cmd = ".\some_exe_which_does_not_exist.exe"
            iex $cmd 
        }
        Catch {
            Write-Error $_.Exception.Message
        }
    }
}

[Operator] $operator = New-Object Operator
$operator.oper1()
```

> The term '.\some_exe_which_does_not_exist.exe' is not recognized as
>   the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program.
>   Check the spelling of the name, or if  a path was included, verify
>   that the path is correct and try again. **At line:1 char:1**
>   + F:\debug\encryption_concat_tests\Untitled1.ps1
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Write-Error], WriteErrorException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WriteErrorException

What could be the reason for this behaviour for methods inside classes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As an aside: [`Invoke-Expression` (`iex`) should generally be avoided](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/powershell/2011/06/03/invoke-expression-considered-harmful/); definitely [don't use it to invoke an external program](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57966347/45375) - just invoke it *directly*, as shown below.

---

In PowerShell class methods:

- Do not use `Write-Error`, as classes are not designed to emit *non-terminating* errors.

  - The only reason you're seeing any output at all is a *bug* as of PowerShell Core 7.0.0-rc.3 with methods whose return type happens to be `[void]` - see [GitHub issue #5331](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/5331#issuecomment-541062514).
- Instead, communicate errors solely by *throwing* them with the `Throw` statement or by *not* catching *terminating* errors (which include exceptions from .NET methods and cmdlet calls with `-ErrorAction Stop`).

  - Note: `Throw` and `-ErrorAction Stop` (or `$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'`) create *script*-terminating (thread-terminating) errors, whereas exceptions thrown by a .NET method (not caught and re-thrown in the class method) only create *statement*-terminating errors; that is, while the class-method body is terminated right away, execution continues in the caller by default; the latter also applies to the call operator (`&`) not finding an executable, errors in expressions such as `1 / 0`, and cmdlet calls that emit statement-terminating errors (the most severe error type they can report) *without* their being promoted to *script*-terminating ones with `-ErrorAction Stop`; see [this GitHub docs issue](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell-Docs/issues/1583) for a comprehensive overview of PowerShell's complex error handling.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59242052/45375) for more information about error handling and stream-output behavior in class methods in particular.

Here's a corrected version of your code.

```sh
class Operator {
    [void] oper1() {
        Try {
            # Try to invoke a non-existent executable.
            & ".\some_exe_which_does_not_exist.exe"
        }
        Catch {
            # Re-throw the error.
            # Alternatively, don't use try / catch, but the error
            # then only aborts the method call, not the entire script.
            Throw
        }
    }
}

$operator = [Operator]::new()
$operator.oper1()
```

Answer (score 0):

I also have this problem! But I really wanted to figure out how to output information and return the desired type of information from the function!
I solved the problem using `Write-Warning`

```
[bool] hidden AddUserToGroup([Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADGroup]$group, [Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADUser]$user)
{
    try
    {
        Add-ADGroupMember -Server $this.server -Identity $group -Members $user;
        return $true;
    }
    catch [System.SystemException]
    {
        Write-Warning $_.Exception.Message;
        return $false;
    }
}
```